# Magento 1.9 category product list in cms block won't display correctly; products shown on random rows

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Working in Magento 1.9, I've used this code in a cms block to display products from a specific category:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="28" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

The products from the category show up, but are distributed randomly on different rows. There are 5 products; 3 appear on the first row, 1 on the second, and 1 on the third.

I've tried adding more products, removing products, and adding column values to the shortcode, always with the same result: 3 products in 3 columns on the first row, then remaining products distributed on individual rows in the first column.

When viewing this particular category page all the products display fine.

I've tried using different category id's, with the same result.

Is there a problem with my shortcode, or some setting that I can change in the backend? I'm not skilled at php, and I don't have access to this client's ftp, so any changes to core files would have to go through another admin for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with magento. This question is about html & styling (CSS).

The last row's problem is this CSS, remove it if you can or rewrite it for this page:

```
.widget .products-grid li.item:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

It's a `.widget` specific style, so that's why you are having the issue only when inserting a widget block of products.